# No color change when code snippets used inside links

Tags: bug, formatting

I enjoy using backticks to format names of code symbols, like `gluPerspective`, in monospace font even in the flow of normal text.  I also enjoy linking the names of such functions to some documentation about them, like [gluPerspective](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml).  Unfortunately, when I do both at once, the result doesn't change color and therefore doesn't look like a link: [`gluPerspective`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml).  (If you mouse over it, it'll get an underline, but if you didn't happen to mouse over it, there's no way to tell it's a link.)

On Stack Overflow this problem doesn't happen. See for example the first paragraph of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169101/how-to-create-a-temporary-file-that-can-be-read-by-a-subprocess), where the link is in monospace font but also colored like any other link.

Can we fix our CSS here so that links show up properly in the monospace font?

Comment: Okay...but that question was opened months ago and there is no sign of any actual action having been taken in response.  How do we bring this to the attention of whoever has the ability to fix it?

Comment: I have no idea; I upvoted both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just noticed that this has apparently been fixed recently.  See [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/53188/9894) for example, where code in links shows up underlined.